# Refactoring in VBA - moving parts of code into function does not work

Tags: vba, excel, refactoring

I am fairly new to VBA Excel. I am trying to refactor some VBA macro by inserting chunk of code into function and then calling the function instead of the chunk. The chunk of code is copy-pasted many times in the macro (only changing one constant). However the old solution works and the new solution with function does not. It does not even throw an error message, it just freezes the whole Excel application. Do you happen to know what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: The macro gets called from SAP, if it makes any difference.

**OLD:**

```
Dim tbl As Object
If ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer.Items("ITEMS").Table Is Nothing Then
  Exit Sub
Else
  Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer.Items("ITEMS").Table
  maxNumRow = ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer.Items("ITEMS").Table.rowCount
  '... (do stuff)
```

**NEW:**

```
Dim tbl As Object
If LinkServer_Table("ITEMS", tbl, maxNumRow) = True Then
  '... (do stuff)

...
Function LinkServer_Table( _
  ByVal name As String, _
  ByRef tbl As Object, _
  Optional ByRef rowCount As Long)

  If ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer.Items(name).Table Is Nothing Then
    LinkServer_Table = False
  Else
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer.Items(name).Table
    rowCount = ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer.Items(name).Table.rowCount
    LinkServer_Table = True
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Usually, refactoring makes code more readable. However I find your old code much clearer than your new one. Your `LinkServer_Table` function does three things and returns three independent outputs; one as a return value and two as `ByRef` parameters. This strikes me as being rather messy. Also you'll still have to add `Else Exit Sub`, so you haven't saved that many lines of code.

Comment: The IF statement encompasses the whole SUB, so the ELSE part is not needed. So my reduction is from 5 lines to 1, at many places in the code. However I understand your objection.

Comment: Well, you removed the `Else : Exit Sub` functionality, so really, to compare apples to apples, we should remove it from your old code as well, so that's going from *3* lines to 1. [But at what cost.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After *Treb* pointed out that there is problem in the "name" parameter, I focused on it and after some trial-error I came with the working version below. I still do not quite understand what is going on, but it's working.

```
Function LinkServer_Table( _
  ByVal name As String, _
  ByRef tbl As Object, _
  Optional ByRef maxRows As Long)

    If ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer.Items(CVar(name)).Table Is Nothing Then
        LinkServer_Table = False
    Else
        Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer.Items(CVar(name)).Table
        maxRows = ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer.Items(CVar(name)).Table.RowCount
        LinkServer_Table = True
    End If
End Function
```

However, I also highly valued *Jean-François Corbett*'s input and tried to refactor the code in some cleaner way. Finally I realized that code can be rewritten directly in place into very short and readable chunk:

```
Dim tbl As Object        
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer.Items("ITEMS").Table
If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
  maxNumRow = tbl.RowCount
  '...(do stuff)
```

Thank you both guys for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the return type of your function:

```
Function LinkServer_Table( _
  ByVal name As String, _
  ByRef tbl As Object, _
  Optional ByRef rowCount As Long) As Boolean
```

Comment: Thanks for fast suggestion. I tried this and it did not help; it stil freezes.

Comment: Ok, at what line does it freeze?

Comment: I dont know the line, I can't seem to debug it when launched from SAP. When debugging it standalone, it stops at the first If in the function and says "Application-defined or object-defined error" (1004). When I tried to dissect the If and procceed with each object individually (If for ThisWorkbook, then If for ThisWorkbook.Container, then If for ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer etc) it complained that Container is not defined. But Container is probably supplied by SAP, so it make sense for such behavior when debugging standalone.

Comment: Ok, let's go back to the original code and add `dim container as Object` `set container = ThisWorkbook.Container` `MsgBox container` at the top. If you need to debug it whet it's launched from SAP, your best bet is to litter the code with `MsgBox` statements...

Comment: One other thought, does it work when you use `ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer.Items("ITEMS")` instead of `ThisWorkbook.Container.LinkServer.Items(name)` in your function?

Comment: And one more thing: How does the macro calling from SAP work? Does SAP open the Excel file and execute the macro?

Comment: Hey Treb, thanks for your efforts. 1st suggestion (MsgBox) - does not work, the same response as before (freeze in online mode and app-defined error in offline mode). 3rd suggestion - yes, I made that clear in my question. 2nd suggestion - BINGO! With literal "ITEMS" in the function, this DOES work! But I do not understand this behaviour. Also, this would counteract the refactoring, since the "tableName" parameter changes over the usage of this function.

Comment: ALthough it is best practice to define a return type of a VBA function, VBA does not require the return type to be defined. If it is not, a variant is returned.